# chrome devtool extension access files in the workspace

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

How do a chrome devtool extension access files in the workspace?

Are there any api?

I want to get and set the files' content.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.getResources`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow#method-getResources), this may fit the bill.

Comment: This api can just access the inspectedWindow's resources,can't access local files.